# I am trying to load DLL in window service, I am getting below exception and my window service was crashed. Can anyone have any idea about this?

Tags: c#

Faulting application name: Demo_38.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x60791ff8
Faulting module name: CleanContentAPI.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x56e6d88b
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000043858
Faulting process id: 0x125c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d732a04ae44470
Faulting application path:
E:\Share\Temp\Processing\ssdc\WorkerServices\Service\V.1.00\Demo_38.exe
Faulting module path: E:\Share\temp\CleanContentSDK\Windows\x64\CleanContentAPI.dll
Report Id: 8b3e3668-9e93-11eb-8100-0050568c3b68
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

I am loading it like below code and using it in Thread:

```
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllPath);
```

Comment: But no actual message like "object reference not set"?

Comment: Sardar, use Tracing and Logging and put an exception handler at the top level of your application so that when it crashes, it logs to Windows log or some file. Otherwise, you are out of luck.

Comment: Given you haven't shown any code, or even a proper exception message and stacktrace, this is unanswerable

Comment: Error 0xc0000005 indicates you are trying to access a memory location not assigned to your program.  The program is on your E drive.  Usually Windows dlls should be on c drive.  Does dll have to run with Admin priviledge.  If running in VS you do not automatically run with Admin.  Try starting VS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: jdweng, The DLL file already in C drive. 
I am loading it like below code:

  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

Comment: 0xc0000005 = access violation = NullReferenceException.
Why not run the application in a debugger?

Comment: What would you do with a DLL loaded via LoadLibrary? Don't you want to DllImport the CleanContentAPI.dll?

Comment: Thomas Weller, I want to load CleanContent.dll at run time, and it will be used by 4 threads simultaneously in window service. but when it is executed the service is getting crashed.
I have taken the faulting detail from the "Event viewer" application log.